# откуда ведется отсчет свойства top для двух дивов?

Tags: html, css

```
div id="reldiv2"
div id="reldiv1"
```

Откуда ведется отсчет top для этих двух дивов?

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
  font: 12px Arial;
}

#normdiv {
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px dashed #999966;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#reldiv1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  border: 1px dashed #669966;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#reldiv2 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px dashed #669966;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#absdiv1 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed #990000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  text-align: center;
}

#absdiv2 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed #990000;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="absdiv1">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #1</span>
  <br />position: absolute; </div>
<div id="reldiv1">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #2</span>
  <br />position: relative; </div>
<div id="reldiv2">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #3</span>
  <br />position: relative; </div>
<div id="absdiv2">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #4</span>
  <br />position: absolute; </div>
<div id="normdiv">
  <br /><span class="bold">DIV #5</span>
  <br />no positioning </div>
```

результат [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

codepen https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true

Comment: от их позиции..

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Kjuri, в вопросе речь про дивы с `position:relative` - причем тут absolute?